# Android SQLite column _id error ,

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to Query in the database.The database is not created in the app, I have created outside, and I am using as [this tutorial](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) explain. But I have an error related with column _id. 
In the Class DatabaseHelper, I have the following code:

```
public Cursor Search(Context context,String search){
        SQLiteDatabase db= getReadableDatabase();
        String cursorFactory = "SELECT * FROM words WHERE eng || ' ' || rus LIKE ?";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(cursorFactory, new String[]{"%" + search + "%"});
        return cursor;
                }
```

In the Activity, the code I wrote is:

```
 public void search(View v){
            text2search= searchText.getText().toString();   
            cursor= myDbHelper.Search(mContext, text2search);
            adapter =new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),R.layout.list_item, 
                        cursor,
                        new String[]{"rusword","engword","kind"},
                        new int[]{R.id.rusWord,R.id.engWord,R.id.knd});
            wordsList.setAdapter(adapter);              
        }
```

And I get the error related with the _id:(in the LogCat)

> 09-03 14:12:38.018: E/AndroidRuntime(16581): Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

But the data base, that I create, it has the "_id" column:( I cant upload image, so here is the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/9a2ol1acrnxmzob/sql-db-rusWjpg.png )

Thank you!

Comment: try to ask db without `*` but with `"_id, rusword, engword, kind"` ... if there is no `_id` column you should get error ...

Answer (score 1):

So problem isn't too tricky. Some adapters, in you case `SimpleCursorAdapter` this adapter needs when are try to select something you need to select column **_id**.
So try this:

```
new String[] {"_id", "rusword", "engword", "kind"}
String cursorFactory = "SELECT _id, [next columns] FROM ...;
```

now it should works.

Similar question is here:

- [`App Crashes On Startup Due To java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
  column '_id' does not
  exist`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974816/app-crashes-on-startup-due-to-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-column-id-d)

**Note:** In the case you don't want to have **_id** column you can use this simple trick:

```
SELECT keyID AS _id FROM TableName
```

Comment: in addition to Note ... keyID(if you have defined key) or just special SQLite column like `ROWID as _id`

Comment: You right man. i just noted when he wanted to have column called id or keyID, f.e. `private static final String KEYID = "id {or idCustomer etc..}"`