# Using SimpleCursorAdapter got IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-adapter

I got a SQLite database and I would like to display data in a listView, I try it with a `SimpleCursorAdapter`:

```
contactAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contact_row, cursor, 
                                         new String[] { MyDb.ACCOUNT_NAME },
                                         new int[] { R.id.contactNameTv });
```

On this very line I get an

> IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exists.

Well, thanks JVM I just don't see what the heck should I do with that, because I don't even use `_id` column and this statement also wrong because I exported the database and opened with sqlite database opener and I can see the column `_id` in the database so it does exist.

Can somebody tell me when this error should appear and what is it trying to tell me ?

E D I T:

njzk2 pointed me right, I wasn't queried the "_id" column in my cursor getting func. Thanks.

Comment: you don't use it, but simplecursoradapter does. it is mandatory to use a cursoradapter

Comment: OK, and why is it keep saying me it is not exists when it does ?:)

Comment: is it in your cursor ? post the cursor projection code

Comment: Oh i got it, it wasnt querried that column i understand now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[App Crashes On Startup Due To java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974816/app-crashes-on-startup-due-to-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-column-id-d)

see the above sample which has same issue like this may be it will help you

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

You should add "_id" field when you create your table.

```
 //example 

   "CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,field1 TEXT, field2 TEXT, etc TEXT)";
```

The Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not work.
Additionally, using {@link android.database.MergeCursor} with this class will not work if the merged Cursors have overlapping values in their "_id"
columns.

## Warning!!

SimpleCursorAdapter this constructor was deprecated in API level 11. This option is discouraged, as it results in Cursor queries being performed on the application's UI thread and thus can cause poor responsiveness or even Application Not Responding errors. As an alternative, use LoaderManager with a CursorLoader.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html

An alternative is to use CursorAdapter and CursorLoader.

CursorAdapter is very useful when you work with databases for example if you want to show a list of data in ListView, GridView or RecyclerView directly from a database.

CursorLoader runs an asynchronous query in the background!

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html

I hope it helps you!!

cheers.